# is active field name breaking this form

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've been getting weird behaviour since I added the active checkbox to this form, the Submit button can only be clicked outside of the the text, and the checked status of the active field is not registering when the form is submitted, it always shows as true. I checked to see if active was a reserved word because the behaviour is so funky, but to no avail. Am I being a noob?

```
<div class="add-form">
    <?= $this->Form->create($member) ?>
        <legend><?= __('Edit Member') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('membership_no');
            echo $this->Form->control('password');
            echo $this->Form->control('email');
            echo $this->Form->control('company_id', ['options' => $companies]);
            echo $this->Form->control('terms_agreed');
            echo $this->Form->control('change_password');
            echo $this->Form->control('active');
        ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

in case it's of any import here is the migration where I added the active column

```
    <?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class AddActiveToMembers extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('members');
        $table->addColumn('active', 'boolean', [
            'default' => true,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with other field name once.

'default'=>true may be returning value '1' ...Remove and check the output.

That is

```
  <?php
  use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

  class AddActiveToMembers extends AbstractMigration
   {
    public function change()
      {
      $table = $this->table('members');
      $table->addColumn('active_col', 'boolean', [
        'default' => true,
        'null' => false,
     ]);
      $table->update();
   }
 }
```

---

OR

---

```
   <?php
   use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

   class AddActiveToMembers extends AbstractMigration
   {
    public function change()
     {
      $table = $this->table('members');
      $table->addColumn('active', 'boolean', [            
        'null' => false,
      ]);
      $table->update();
     }
   }
```